# Celery task blocked in Django view with a AWS SQS broker

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs, django-celery

I am trying to run a celery task in a Django view using `my_task.delay()`. However, the task is never executed and the code is blocked on that line and the view never renders. I am using AWS SQS as a broker with an IAM user with full access to SQS.

What am I doing wrong?

**Running celery and Django**

I am running celery like this:

```
celery -A app worker -l info
```

And I am starting my Django server locally in another terminal using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The celery command outputs:

```
-------------- celery@LAPTOP-02019EM6 v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-10-10.0.16299 2018-02-07 13:48:18
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app:0x6372c18
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqs://**redacted**:**@localhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF
--- ***** -----
-------------- [queues]
                .> my-queue      exchange=my-queue(direct) key=my-queue


[tasks]
. app.celery.debug_task
. counter.tasks.my_task

[2018-02-07 13:48:19,262: INFO/MainProcess] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sa-east-1.queue.amazonaws.com
[2018-02-07 13:48:19,868: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 20196 calling self.run()
[2018-02-07 13:48:19,918: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 19984 calling self.run()
[2018-02-07 13:48:19,947: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 16024 calling self.run()
[2018-02-07 13:48:20,004: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 19572 calling self.run()
[2018-02-07 13:48:20,815: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqs://**redacted**:**@localhost//
[2018-02-07 13:48:20,930: INFO/MainProcess] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sa-east-1.queue.amazonaws.com
[2018-02-07 13:48:21,307: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\users\nicolas\anaconda3\envs\djangocelery\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2018-02-07 13:48:21,311: INFO/MainProcess] celery@LAPTOP-02019EM6 ready.
```

**views.py**

```
from .tasks import my_task

def index(request):
    print('New request') # This is called
    my_task.delay()
    # Never reaches here
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

**tasks.py**

```
...
@shared_task
def my_task():
    print('Task ran successfully') # never prints anything
```

**settings.py**

My configuration is the following:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'sqs://'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'sa-east-1',
}
CELERY_BROKER_USER = '****************'
CELERY_BROKER_PASSWORD = '***************************'
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'my-queue'
```

**Versions:**

I use the following version of Django and Celery:

```
Django==2.0.2
django-celery==3.2.2
celery==4.1.0
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also note that even if I use the default queue, I have the same issue. In that case, the celery queue will be created in SQS but the code would still be stuck when calling the task with .delay

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @butteredtoast: I haven't but I have since used celery with django successfully in another project. Two things I haven't tried for this pet project but that I have used successfully later: 1) on Windows, use the `eventlet` option and 2) install `pycurl` (not sure if I had it here). For my current use of celery, I am also using RabbitMQ (through the CloudAMPQ service) instead of Amazon SQS.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe you are still interested. I got Celery with Django and SQS running and don't see any errors in your code. Maybe you missed something in the celery.py file? Here is my code for comparing.

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangoappname.settings')

# do not use namespace because default amqp broker would be called
app = Celery('lsaweb')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Have you also checked if SQS is getting messages (try polling in the SQS administration area)?